# from second ViewController to first ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 ViewControllers, in 1st - TableView and in 2nd - button with label on it. When I click on the button in 2nd ViewController I need to go back on TableView and set in

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text
```

text from label on the button.

For go back to first view I use:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

but how I can set label from second view to:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text
```

in first view?????

Comment: You can't. Do it in the `viewWillAppear` method instead.

Comment: you can't do it even in viewWillAppear, without implementing protocols

Comment: @TeodorCarstea While that's roughly true, the key take-home message is that when an active view controller wants to trigger the changing of something in the view that has received `viewDidDisappear`, whatever mechanism you use for the updating should _not_ update the inactive view directly (that view could have been released in the case of a `didReceiveMemoryWarning`). You must update your model and only when the other view controller becomes active and receives `viewWillAppear`, should UI changes should be performed.

Comment: @RobertRyan, agree. Question: you said "... should not update the inactive view directly...", what is the use? Updating an inactive view will do no visible changes, even if you try doing that. So first model, than viewWillAppear, as you said.

Comment: @TeodorCarstea The common scenario is how to update parent right before dismissing the child. I actually saw another SO on precisely this topic, where someone responded with a nicely detailed answer about how to use delegates to do this, but proceeded to have the delegate's callback method innocuously update the parent view with `self.label.text=...` before the child had been dismissed. So, with no offense to Martol1ni, while his answer is terribly constructive, there is a kernel of an under-appreciated fact, that one shouldn't have delegate method update UI. Sounds like we're agreed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define a protocol & delegate in the second view controller

```
@protocol SecondViewController;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SecondViewController> delegate;

@end


@protocol SecondViewController <NSObject>
- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)controller didTappedOnButton:(UIButton *)button;
@end
```

then when the button is tapped call the delegate:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // do somthing..

    // then tell the delegate about the button tapped
    [self.delegate secondViewController:self didTappedOnButton:sender];
}
```

In your first view controller implement the protocol

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
```

when you push the second view controller, set the first as the second delegate:

```
- (void)someMethodThatPushTheSecondViewController
{
    SecondViewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
    svc.delegate = self;
}
```

And implement the delegate method to get notified when the button tapped

```
- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)controller didTappedOnButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    // do somthing after button tapped
    // you can get the button title from button.titleLabel.text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a parent class method or property you gotta implement a protocol, and use it's delegates. You can access child class methods/properties using it's class object that you create in the current (parent) class. But how you want to access a parent class entity from a child class? YES, implementing protocols.

Or the newbie way: after tapping your button, save the needed value into NSUserDefaults. Then, when you go to your parent class (viewController 1), ion viewWillAppear, check that saved value, and if it's not nil, display it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```